# group collaboration open source php app

Tags: php, collaboration

I am on a committee that would benefit from an online application that allows the members to collaborate w/ members.

I would want the ability to post messages and upload documents.

Is there any free, easy to install on your server apps that you would suggest?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more information. "Collaborate" is far too generic a descriptor for me to provide any sort of meaningful response.

Comment: a mix of basecamp and a document library, w/ a msg board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want something similar to BaseCamp, you should try out [ProjectPier](http://www.projectpier.org/).

If you think you'll need more community features than a project management tool can offer, I would suggest jumping into [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).

Answer (score 0):

With such broad requirements there are going to be 1000's of packages to choose from.  Something like [TikiWiki](http://info.tikiwiki.org/tiki-index.php) would probably do the job (it might even be overkill depending on your needs).

Comment: a mix of basecamp and a document library, w/ a msg board.